# addClass to a href link acccoring to the location.href using jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to have the following code written more efficiently?

Please note that this section of navigation is part of a CMS and is set to hidden hence you won't see it expanded. I have the following code that works i.e re writes the nav items and adds a class of current according to the location.href but I was hoping it could be written more efficiently?

HTML

```
    <ul>
      <li><a class="current" href="#"><strong>Level 1</strong></a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li><a class="" href="#">sub level</a></li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">sub level</a></li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">sub level</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

jQuery

The first part rewrites the hidden section

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('menu li:eq(4)').html('<ul><li><a href="/level1" class="current"><strong>level1</strong></a>'
    +'<ul class="sub"><li><a href="/sub-level-a" class="">Sub Level A</a></li>'
    +'<li><a href="/sub-level-b" class="">Sub Level B</a></li>'
    +'<li><a href="/sub-level-c" class="">Sub Level C</a></li></ul></li></ul>');
```

});

Adds Class

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("/ucpoolvehicles")!=-1)
                    {
        $("ul.sub li a:eq(0)").addClass("current");
                    } else {

        $("ul.sub li a:eq(0)").removeClass("current");
        }
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("/car-rental")!=-1)
                    {
        $("ul.sub li a:eq(1)").addClass("current");
                    } else {

        $("ul.sub li a:eq(1)").removeClass("current");
        }

        if(window.location.href.indexOf("/private-vehicle-usage")!=-1)
                    {
        $("ul.sub li a:eq(2)").addClass("current");
                    } else {

        $("ul.sub li a:eq(2)").removeClass("current");

        }

        });
```

I hope I'm clear in with my instructions
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks codingbiz, yes it works

Comment: I think this is a bit too specific to fit as a question here. Keep in mind, searching for this on Google *should* bring up some very useful resources. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment Purmou, but you're damned if you do and damned if you don't... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.sub li a").removeClass("current");
    var href = window.location.href;
    if (href.indexOf("/ucpoolvehicles") != -1) {
        $("ul.sub li a:eq(0)").addClass("current");
    } else if (href.indexOf("/car-rental") != -1) {
        $("ul.sub li a:eq(1)").addClass("current");
    } else if (href.indexOf("/private-vehicle-usage") != -1) {
        $("ul.sub li a:eq(2)").addClass("current");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks sp00m, I understand the logic and will apply it rather than what I have.

Answer (score 0):

This will work without hidden section

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    alert(window.location.href);

    var url = window.location.href;

    // Will only work if string in href matches with location
    $('ul.sub li a[href="' + url + '"]').addClass('active');

    // Will also work for relative and absolute hrefs
    $('ul.sub li a').filter(function () {
        return this.href == url;
    }).addClass('active');
});
```